# Use swagger.json file generated in post build actions in Swashbuckle instead of the file generated at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

In my .NET 6 microservice I am generating the swagger.json file with Swashbuckle CLI package and the post build commands. Now I would like to use this json instead of the one generated at runtime by the Swashbuckle package so that the response is faster than the current one.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the generated file in the build output and use the "UseStaticFiles()" method to serve it.

For example include the generated file in the output under a new directory called "swaggerfiles", then in the configuration you can have (for example):

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swaggerfiles/swagger.json", "My microservice v1"));
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "swaggerfiles")),
        RequestPath = "/swaggerfiles"
    });
```

Comment: In my case I dinamically add the versioning like this:
 ```app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                // Build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
            });```
so you solution is not working. How should I specify the version folders?

Comment: Are the files placed in folders matching their groupnames?

Comment: The files are in swagger/"groupname"/.

Comment: I found it. You sent me in the right direction. Here there is how it is supposed to work: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1933. The swagger folder should be placed in wwwroot/, the UseSwagger middlware must be removed and replaced with the UseStaticFiles without parameters. In my case it is working. Thank you